# Perl Script (running slow) taking a minute to replace the simple regex

Tags: regex, perl

Perl script taking (running slowly) a minute to replace the following regex:

```
$str = '<![CDATA[$..$]]>;
```

I have a file contains `<![CDATA[$..$]]>` (not less than 1000 occurrences) latex/tex coding in CDATA. Hence I need to change this into Comment tag and processing instruction like `<!--<![CDATA[--><?processingInstruction $..$?><!--]]>-->`.

```
$SqrBrLoopMany = qw/((?:[^\[\]]*(?:{(?:[^\[\]]*(?:{[^\[\]]*})*[^\[\]]*)*})*[^\[\]]*)*)/; # This is for using `\[ <whatever> \]` Square bracket.

$str=~s/(\<\!\[CDATA\[)$SqrBrLoopMany(\]\]>)/<\!\-\-$1\-\-><\?processingInstruction $2\?><\!\-\-$3\-\->/sg;
```

The above regex I am doing however the script takes a minute to replace the output.

Output should be:

`<!--<![CDATA[--><?processingInstruction $..$?><!--]]>-->`

It would be appreciated if someone help on this one.

Comment: This is `XML` - don't use regex. This is a bad plan.

Comment: Is it a requirement that it should only match if the braces (`{ }`) and/or brackets (`[ ]`) inside the CDATA are balanced?

Comment: Only Square brackets `( [ ] )`...

Comment: Thanks to all I got it.

Comment: @Sobrique CDATA sections can't be nested, therefore it's actually possible to extract them with a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest possible:

```
s/<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)]]>/<!--<![CDATA[--><?processingInstruction $1?><!--]]>-->/sg
```

CDATA can not contain any nested structures, so the pattern just looks for the starting `<![CDATA[` and closest ending `]]>`, and matches everything in between.

The reason your pattern is running slowly, is because you are matching non-brackets (`[^\[\]]`) in between braces `{ ... }`. If the CDATA section contains `[` or `]`that are not part of the ending `]]>`, it will fail and try to backtrack each of the `[^\[\]]*` in turn, leading to quintic (O(x<sup>5</sup>)) execution time.

---

If square brackets are required to be balanced for it to match, you could do

```
s/<!\[CDATA\[(([^][]|\[(?2)*?])*?)]]>/<!--<![CDATA[--><?processingInstruction $1?><!--]]>-->/sg
```

The `(?2)` will recursively match the second subpattern/capture group again. This should work in both Perl and PCRE based regex engines.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LmClY9/2

Comment: `<![CDATA[$[\hat {T}_{W},\hat {Q}_{F}]=\textbf {0}$]]>` One of the occurrences for your review.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Markus Jarderot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933001/perl-script-running-slow-taking-a-minute-to-replace-the-simple-regex/40934477) given the way/answer to achieve this:

```
$str=~s/(\<\!\[CDATA\[)([^\]\]>]*)(\]\]>)/<\!\-\-$1\-\-><\?xmltex $2\?><\!\-\-$3\-\->/sg;

<!\[CDATA\[(.*?)]]> Instead of <!\[CDATA\[([^\]\]>]*)]]>
```